# Difference between scipy.optimize.curve_fit and linear least squares

Tags: scipy, linear-regression, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am struggling to find information on what exactly the scipy.optimize.curve_fit function does to fit (for example) exponential data and how would does this method differ from just linearizing the data and directly computing the linear fit using the general formulas for a weighted linear least squares fit?

Answer (score 0):

It's Levenberg-Marquadt nonlinear fitting for unbounded problems and a trust-region variant when bounds are given. See the references in the docstring of least_squares.